# Implementing sugar syntax

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, programming-languages, language-features, language-translation

At which stage of compiling (scanning, parsing, some part of semantic analysis, or maybe even 
code generation) is syntax sugar usually handled, how and what are the reasons for it?

Comment: Depending on the language, syntax sugar is often implemented in the source itself - that is, outside the compiler chain. One very popular example is jQuery which introduces syntax sugar as a library in javascript itself - without requiring the user to recompile their web browsers.

Comment: Other languages which are very easy to implement syntax sugar directly in the language itself include lisp (Scheme etc.) and tcl. One extreme example is the object-oriented programming features in lisp and tcl were originally implemented directly in the language without needing any modification to the compiler/parser

Comment: @slebetman - Taking into account a possible need for de-sugaring and the fact that source has to go through all of the compiler stages anyway, would you advise to perform the in-source replacements? Anyway, how would the debugging work? I can't imagine it.

Comment: Not in-source replacements. The sugar are just functions. It just so happens that the syntax of some languages are so minimal that function calls can look like syntax

Comment: @slebetman - you mean something like what's described on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)? (`set_array(Array, vector(i,j), value)` to `Array[i,j] = value`)

Comment: Yes. For example, in tcl, there are no expressions - just function calls (imagine bash or dos and you'll understand tcl syntax). So that Array syntax can easily be implemented as a function that looks something like this: `proc Array {vector_string operand value} {...}` and you can now type `Array [i,j] = value`. You can even get rid of that whitespace between `Array` and `[]` by using a feature called the `unknown` function which gets called whenever you try to call an undefined function.

Comment: @slebetman - That's actually an interesting way of introducing syntactic sugar to the language. I'll definitely think about it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest place to do it is often at the point of building the AST -- i.e., during the parse itself -- because that makes the desugaring apparent and verifiable, and thereafter the sugar does not need to be dealt with in any way during semantic analysis and code generation.

That's a very general guideline and there are innumerable circumstances in which you might choose a  different strategy.